# Stop graph touching zero in ggplot geom_freqpoly function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a frequency plot using the geom_freqpoly function in ggplot2. I have a large data set of social media comments across 14 months and am plotting the number of comments for each week of that data. I am using this code, first converting the UTC to POSIXct and the doing the frequency plot:

```
ggplot(data = TRP) + 
  geom_freqpoly(mapping = aes(x = created_utc), binwidth = 604800)
```

This is creating a plot that looks like this:

[image: Frequency Plit]

I want however to top and tail the plot, as it touches 'zero' at both the start and end, making it look like there was rapid growth and rapid decline. This is not the case as this is simply a snapshot of the data, which exists before and after my analysis. The data begins at the 4,000 mark and ends at around 2,000 and I want it represented like that. I have checked the 'pad' instruction and have insured it is set at FALSE.

Any help as to why this may be occurring would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adjusting the geom_freqpoly to work differently than intended, it might be simpler to calculate the weekly totals yourself and use `geom_line`:

```
library(lubridate); library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
        datetime = ymd_h(2018010101) + dhours(runif(1000, 0, 14*30*24))
      )

df %>%
  count(week_count = floor_date(datetime, "1 week")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(week_count, n)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]